# while adding element by 'AddRange()' in List of object following exception arrives

Tags: c#, list, generics

"Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds."

I have not mentioned any size while creating destination list (in where I'm adding object) and  source list (from where I'm adding objects in destination list)

Here is similar code what I'm doing.

```
List<Obj> sourceList = respObj.List;

if (sourceList  != null)
{
     destinationList.AddRange(sourceList);
}
```

here sourceList is being returned from a method calling and there also I'm not mentioning any size or index while creating it.
it is as simple as this.

```
//destination list is globally declared, and initialized in constructor
public List<Obj> destinationList;
//Constructor
public Class()
{
    destinationList = new List<Obj>();
}

List<Obj> Method()
{
     List<Obj> sourceList = new List<Obj>();
     foreach(Obj obj in AlreadyGeneratedObjList)
     {
          if(SatisfyingCondition(obj))
          {
               sourceList.Add(obj);
          }  
     }
     return sourceList;
}
```

Exception occurs on "AddRange()" method

Comment: show the declaration of your `destinationList`

Comment: destinationList is also simply declared as `new List<Obj>()` in constructor

Comment: destinationList is array not list. I cant see reason why AddRange fails on list

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary destination list is `List<Obj>` , it is generic list.

Answer (score 2):

I assume `destinationList` is declared as

```
var destinationList = [?]{}; // ? being some size
```

The problem with this is that your array can't resize automatically which is what is needed for `.AddRange()` to be able to add contents of `sourceList` into it.

The way to solve this would be to either declare `destinationList` as a list

```
var destinationList = new List<obj>{};
```

or as an array with a correct size, ie. size that would accommodate the size of `sourceList` after it has been filtered. This may not be the best way to go about it though.

My personal recommendation would be to use a `List<>`.

Also don't forget to check that the filtered `sourceList` is not empty or null.

**Edit**

You should consider changing this as follows

```
if (sourceList != null && sourceList.Count > 0)
{
     destinationList.AddRange(sourceList);
}
else
{
     //destinationList = sourceList;
     // If the sourceList is ever null it will make every subsequent call
     // destinationList fail with a NullReference exception.

     destinationList.Clear();
}
```

Comment: I agree on your suggestion and `destinationList` is a List only. and also I'm checking for Null. (you can see it in sample code I have posted)

Comment: It's hard to say what else could be wrong without seeing the whole flow of the application in this case but I think you will have an issue as soon as the sourceList is null for the first time. After that you will start getting NullReference exceptions. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, I must say that is a serious problem you have shown. Thank you for that. yes my really issue must be something different. I have to check in more details. will update if I get something.

Comment: @AmitNatural You know how they say "sharing is caring" ;)